# How do I repeat a string in a data.frame column n times

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm trying to do the following in dplyr:

If I had a dataframe with sequences (df) and wanted to repeat the sequences in each row by n times (df2), how can I get a table that can do this in dplyr (answer = df2)? Thanks in advance!

```
df <- data.frame(start = c("ATG", "ATG", "ATG"), 
                 seq = c("AAACCCTTT", "AAACCCTTT", "AAACCCTTT"), 
                 stop = c("TAG", "TAG", "TAG"))

df1 <- data.frame(n = c("1", "2", "3"))

df2 <- data.frame(start = c("ATG", "ATGATG", "ATGATGATG"), 
                  seq = c("AAACCCTTT", "AAACCCTTTAAACCCTTT", "AAACCCTTTAAACCCTTTAAACCCTTT"), 
                  stop = c("TAG", "TAGTAG", "TAGTAGTAG"))
```

Comment: One option in baseR: `as.data.frame(Map(strrep, df, df1))`

Comment: Thanks, this worked beautifully!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `mutate` with `across`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
     mutate(across(everything(), ~ strrep(., df1$n)))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df <- data.frame(start = c("ATG", "ATG", "ATG"), 
                 seq = c("AAACCCTTT", "AAACCCTTT", "AAACCCTTT"), 
                 stop = c("TAG", "TAG", "TAG"))

df1 <- data.frame(n=1:3)

df2 <-
  df %>%
  bind_cols(df1) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(start:stop),~strrep(.,n))

df2
```

Comment: In dplyr 1.0 we can use this in place of the mutate_at:        `mutate(across(start:stop, ~strrep(., n)))`

Answer (score 2):

Base R:

```
df2 <- df
df2[] <- mapply(strrep, df, df1)
df2

      start                         seq      stop
1       ATG                   AAACCCTTT       TAG
2    ATGATG          AAACCCTTTAAACCCTTT    TAGTAG
3 ATGATGATG AAACCCTTTAAACCCTTTAAACCCTTT TAGTAGTAG
```